# wsdl based webservice in .net changes <xs> tag to <s>

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have wsdl file sent by the client with this rules given:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="PersonInfoTransactionService" targetNamespace="http://example.com/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/" version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="getPersonInfo" type="tns:getPersonInfo"/>

  <xs:element name="getPersonInfoResponse" type="tns:getPersonInfoResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="personInfoRequest" type="tns:PersonInfoRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="personInfoResponse" type="tns:PersonInfoResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="getPersonInfo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PersonInfoRequest" type="tns:PersonInfoRequest"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PersonInfoRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="adress" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dob" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sex" type="tns:sex"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nationality" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getPersonInfoResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PersonInfoResponse" type="tns:PersonInfoResponse"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PersonInfoResponse">
    <xs:sequence>

      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="last_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="first_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fathers_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="adress" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dob" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sex" type="tns:sex"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nationality" type="tns:nationality"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

   <xs:simpleType name="sex">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Male"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Female"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Unknown"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="nationality">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="AFGHANISTAN"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="ALAND ISLANDS"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="ALBANIA"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getPersonInfoResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getPersonInfoResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getPersonInfo">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getPersonInfo" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="PersonInfoTransaction">
    <wsdl:operation name="getPersonInfo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getPersonInfo" name="getPersonInfo">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getPersonInfoResponse" name="getPersonInfoResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:PersonInfoTransaction">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPersonInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getPersonInfo">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getPersonInfoResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="PersonInfoTransactionService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoapBinding" name="PersonInfoTransactionPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/demo/PersonInfoTransaction"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

So, I created corresponding .cs file so that it could generate the above requested wsdl for me. But it generated the wsdl below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http:/example.coom/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http:/example.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http:/example.com/">
      <s:element name="getPersonInfo">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="personInfoRequest" type="tns:PersonInfoRequest" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="PersonInfoRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="adress" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dob" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sex" nillable="true" type="tns:sex" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nationality" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:simpleType name="sex">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="Male" />
          <s:enumeration value="Female" />
          <s:enumeration value="Unknown" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
      <s:element name="getPersonInfoResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getPersonInfoResult" type="tns:ArrayOfPersonInfoResponse" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfPersonInfoResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PersonInfoResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:PersonInfoResponse" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="PersonInfoResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fathers_name" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="adress" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dob" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sex" nillable="true" type="tns:sex" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="nationality" nillable="true" type="tns:nationality" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:simpleType name="nationality">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="AFGHANISTAN" />
          <s:enumeration value="ALAND ISLANDS" />
          <s:enumeration value="ALBANIA" />
          <s:enumeration value="ALGERIA" />

        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getPersonInfoSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getPersonInfo" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getPersonInfoSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getPersonInfoResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="getPersonInfo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getPersonInfoSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getPersonInfoSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap" type="tns:PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getPersonInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http:/example.com/getPersonInfo" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap12" type="tns:PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getPersonInfo">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http:/example.com/getPersonInfo" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="PersonInfoTransactionService">
    <wsdl:port name="PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap" binding="tns:PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:7345/abc/PersonInfoTransactionService.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap12" binding="tns:PersonInfoTransactionServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:7345/abc/PersonInfoTransactionService.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My main question is can I use WSDL directly without having to use .cs file to create WSDL file or what can I modify to create the  tag rather than  tag in the document. Or How can I control or modify WSDL by using `web-services` method?

Answer (score 0):

The xs and s being reffered to are namespace prefixes. The actual namespace prefix does not matter, what matters is what it corresponds to.

xs refers to the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" (xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
s also refers to same namespace (xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")

So s or xs should not matter.